# Delete touch around a dialog in Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, dialog

I'm looking at how to remove the effect of the touch around a dialog

I created a dialog when there is no connection detected

**Code**

```
@Override
            public void onErrorResponse(String _param1, String _param2) {
                final String _tag = _param1;
                final String _message = _param2;
                nc.setTitle("No connection");
                nc.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                nc.setMessage("Turn on your connection and then relaunch the app");
                nc.setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface _dialog, int _which) {
                        i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
                nc.setNegativeButton("Close App", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface _dialog, int _which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                nc.create().show();
            }
        };
    }
```

When the dialog appears it must make the 350x100

When I click on the screen around the dialog it removes

**I would like to know if it is possible to remove the touch around the dialog when it is displayed ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);`. It will still allow you to cancel the dialog with back button, but it will prevent the dialog from closing when touching around it.

**EDIT**

In your code you should change the `nc.create().show();` at the end to:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = nc.create();
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank you, where exactly I have to add it please?

Comment: It works superb well, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add **setCancelable(false)** during creating

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog